# How can I wait for an asynchronously created object to be completely available before invoking a callback?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a function that will create a new marker. I need to be able to process some of the properties of the new marker in the callback. The problem is that `marker` is immediately created and can be used to invoke the callback, but some properties are not yet available.

If I wait two seconds before trying to access the properties, it works just fine - this leads me to believe that the object is still asynchronously generating itself after being created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latLng
  });

  function placeMarker(map, latLng, callback, callback2){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map });

        callback(marker);
        callback2(marker);
    }

    placeMarker(map, latLng, function(marker){
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            console.log(marker.Xg.Oa)
        }, 2000);
    }, function(marker){
        console.log(marker.Xg.Oa);
    });

}
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example the callback:

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    console.log(marker.Xg.Oa)
}, 2000);
```

yields the correct response. But the callback that doesn't wait shows an undefined error:

```
function(marker){
    console.log(marker.Xg.Oa);
}
```

I'm using a the Google Maps Javascript API library here, and messing with the google.maps stuff isn't an option for obvious reasons. I want to pass the entire object to the callback but I need to ensure that the latLng information (`marker.Xg.Oa`) exists before invoking it. How can I ensure that it's there before invoking the callback?

Comment: Do you know anything about promises? Will add an answer that might help...

Comment: I know _of_ them, but as far as I know they aren't part of vanilla JS (which would be preferable). I'm open to using them if that's whats needed.

Comment: There's what they call *polyfills*, in case you haven't heard of them.

Comment: @geocodezip The 3rd party library I mention is the google-maps API, which I've tagged. I feel like the example shown is just the right size for an example. What would you prefer that I add(or remove)? I'll look into finding a better way to access the property.

Comment: As I said **do not access undocumented properties of the Google Maps Javascript API v3** (i.e. `marker.Xg.Oa`), they can and do change with every release.  What information are you trying to retrieve from the marker? Why do you believe it isn't available?

Comment: @geocodezip, I was trying to get the position of the marker - which as you suggest it much better accomplished with a documented method: `marker.getPosition()`, and solves my core problem quite well. (I guess this is an XY question)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NB: I have NOT tested this but something along these lines...

```
var map = //...
var latLng = //...

function placeMarker(map, latLng, callback){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)(){

        getMarker().then(function(marker){
            //The marker is immediately available
            console.log(marker); //me {__gm: Object, ... }

            //Try to get the value we need
            console.log(marker.Xg.Oa); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Oa' of undefined

            //wait two seconds and try again
            setTimeout(function(){ console.log(marker.Xg.Oa) }, 2000); // L {} (this is the expected output)

            while(!marker.Xg.Oa){ //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Oa' of undefined
                callback(marker.Xg.Oa);
            }

            resolve(true);
        });
    });

}

function getMarker()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map 
        });

        resolve(marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to create a more testable example. But I suspect this is the direction I will be heading.

Comment: [After a discussion meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308444/ive-asked-an-xy-question-what-should-i-do-with-it) - I'm accepting this answer as it actually addresses the question I asked - but it should be noted (I'd appreciate if you edited the answer) that it's based on bad practices of accessing the google maps objects in a poor way.