# Loop through google Maps Api in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, for-loop

I have $scope.contacts with various customer and their addresses. I want to loop through all the addresses, send them to the google API and attach the lat/lng for later use in Google Maps.

Thats what I have so far:

```
 //Get already the Geodata of the selected GroupContacts
              for (var p = 0; p < $scope.contacts.length;p++) {
                  var street = $scope.contacts[p].address;
                  var zip = $scope.contacts[p].postcode;
                  var city = $scope.contacts[p].city;
                        vermittlungService.getGoogleData(street,zip,city).then(function(response){
                        $rootScope.contacts[p].lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        $rootScope.contacts[p].lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng; //attach to the $scope
                      }); 


                  console.log($scope.contacts);  
                  };
```

What i understand that the [p] value in the async call changed already the value, so i can't attacht the correct lat/lng to the contact. I get error ": Cannot read property '1' of undefined" in console.

How can I wait with the loop untit the data has arrived and then continue.

Thanks!
edit: This is my get the Google Data service

```
//Fetch Google API from Adress - Returns geoDataObject
this.getGoogleData = function(street,zip,city) {
return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=            ' + street + '+' + zip + '+' + city + APIKEY)
            .then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                    })
    };
```

SOLUTION: I need to wrap the logic in a function. Then it works!

```
  for (var p = 0; p < $scope.contacts.length;p++) {

(function(p) { 
setTimeout(function() {
  var street = $scope.contacts[p].address;
  var zip = $scope.contacts[p].postcode;
  var city = $scope.contacts[p].city;

            vermittlungService.getGoogleData(street,zip,city,apiKey).then(function(response){
    $rootScope.contacts[p].lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    $rootScope.contacts[p].lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng; //attach to the $scope
  }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
  });
  }, 250*p);
 })(p);
});
```

Comment: Take a look at one of my previous answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245495/how-can-i-wait-for-an-asynchronously-created-object-to-be-completely-available-b/33245778#33245778

Comment: Hmm, i think this is not the same problem. I have problems after i receive the response to attach it to the right object key. Cause the loop is faster thatn the ajax call

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping process by anonymous function?

```
for (var p = 0; p < $scope.contacts.length;p++) {
  !function() {
    var street = $scope.contacts[p].address;
    var zip    = $scope.contacts[p].postcode;
    var city   = $scope.contacts[p].city;

    vermittlungService.getGoogleData(street, zip, city).then(function(response) {
      $rootScope.contacts[p].lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      $rootScope.contacts[p].lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    }); 

    console.log($scope.contacts);
  }();
};
```

Comment: Tried this but it is now working. The solution above works!

Comment: But the answer is useful, cause wrapping it in a function is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $q for resolving the promise in the service http call, then setting a timeout for the function? (I believe google maps api limits the number of calls to four per second, so you'd use 250 msec).

So your service call would look something like:

```
this.getGoogleData = function(street,zip,city,apiKey) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + street + '+' + zip + '+' + city +'&key=' + apiKey)
    .then(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response);
    }, function(reason) {
      deferred.reject(reason);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

And your series of calls as it iterates through your contacts list:

```
for (var p = 0; p < $scope.contacts.length;p++) {

  (function(p) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      var street = $scope.contacts[p].address;
      var zip = $scope.contacts[p].postcode;
      var city = $scope.contacts[p].city;

      vermittlungService.getGoogleData(street,zip,city,apiKey).then(function(response){
        $rootScope.contacts[p].lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        $rootScope.contacts[p].lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng; //attach to the $scope
      }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });
    }, 250*p);
  })(p);
});
```

Comment: This is working! Thanks! Can you explain me what the $q is doing exactly? I tried it before but could not make it work. So when i call the service it only returns something when the data is received and then it goes further to the loop? Does it stop the call for a moment?

Comment: I didn't have to use $q deferred in my service. I wrapped the logic in this p function and it is working. So the correct answer is to put it in a function!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. The $q service creates a promise object to be fulfilled when the http call returns, whether successfully or in error. There's a lot of [good writeups](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises) on [the subject](http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/), if you're curious.